# JSch exception: No Configuration was registered named com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, jaas

I'm running this code, but get an exception.

```
Session session = null;  
Channel channel = null;  

JSch jsch = new JSch();  
session = jsch.getSession(ftpUserName, ftpHost, ftpPort);  
if (session == null) {  
    throw new Exception("session is null");  
}  
session.setPassword(ftpPassword);  
session.setTimeout(100000);  
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");  
session.connect();
```

This code is working properly in the local development environment. However, when deployed in the test environment reported abnormal. Test environment for the linux environment, the deployment of middleware for the weblogic11, the use of jdk are oracle 1.6.45.

```
Exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Configuration was registered that can handle the configuration named com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate
at com.bea.common.security.jdkutils.JAASConfiguration.getAppConfigurationEntry(JAASConfiguration.java:130)
at sun.security.jgss.LoginConfigImpl.getAppConfigurationEntry(LoginConfigImpl.java:139)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:243)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:499)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSUtil.login(GSSUtil.java:244)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util.getTicket(Krb5Util.java:136)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential$1.run(Krb5InitCredential.java:328)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getTgt(Krb5InitCredential.java:325)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:128)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:106)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:172)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:209)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:195)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:162)
at com.jcraft.jsch.jgss.GSSContextKrb5.init(GSSContextKrb5.java:129)
at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthGSSAPIWithMIC.start(UserAuthGSSAPIWithMIC.java:135)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:470)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at com.sinosoft.FXQ.util.SftpUtils.downloadSftpFile(SftpUtils.java:57)
at com.sinosoft.FXQ.blackList.action.BLBlackListAction.extractBlackList(BLBlackListAction.java:47)
at com.sinosoft.FXQ.task.DownBlackListDataTask.run(DownBlackListDataTask.java:93)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

Comment: Here "session.connect ();" error

Comment: Never use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, unless you do not care about security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As @Chris already answered*, JSch tries by default Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication.

As you do not seem to want that, remove Kerberos/GSSAPI (`gssapi-with-mic`) from the the default JSch list of authentication methods (`gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password`):

```
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! It works very well!

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

The error message you are getting pertains to Kerberos which is a network authentication protocol.  I see that in your session configuration you do not explicitly specify your authentication protocol.  Because of that I believe that JSch is, for whatever reason, defaulting to Kerberos even though you are supplying a username and a password.

#### The Fix

I think the easiest way to fix this is to modify your `setConfig` method to include a large variety of authentication protocols.  With all of these enabled and your username and password specified you will likely authenticate on most environments.

```
   Hashtable<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<String, String>();
   properties.put("PreferredAuthentications", "gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
   properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

   session.setConfig(properties);
```

#### Still Not Working?

If the above modification doesn't work try the following.

Create a new class called *SessionUserInfo.java*

```
public class SessionUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive {

    private String password;
    private String passPhrase;
    public SessionUserInfo() {
        password = "";
        passPhrase = "";
    }

    public SessionUserInfo (String password, String passPhrase) {
        this.password = password;
        this.passPhrase = passPhrase;
    }

    public String getPassphrase() {
        return passPhrase;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public boolean promptPassphrase(String phrase) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean promptPassword(String password) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean promptYesNo(String bool) {
        return true;
    }

    public void showMessage(String message) {
        // Do Nothing
    }
}
```

Then modify your code as follows.

```
 public static void downloadSftpFile(String ftpHost, String ftpUserName,  
        String ftpPassword, int ftpPort, String ftpPath, String localPath,  
        String fileName) throws Exception { 
    Session session = null;  
    Channel channel = null;  

    JSch jsch = new JSch();  
    session = jsch.getSession(ftpUserName, ftpHost, ftpPort);  
    if (session == null) {  
        throw new Exception("session is null");  
    }  
    session.setPassword(ftpPassword);  
    session.setTimeout(100000);  

   Hashtable<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<String, String>();
   properties.put("PreferredAuthentications", "gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
   properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

   session.setConfig(properties);
   session.setUserInfo(new SessionUserInfo(ftpPassword, null));
    session.connect();  

    channel = session.openChannel("sftp");  
    channel.connect();  
    ChannelSftp chSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;  

    String ftpFilePath = ftpPath + "/" + fileName;  
    String localFilePath = localPath + File.separatorChar + fileName;  

    try {  
        chSftp.get(ftpFilePath, localPath);  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        logger.info("download error.");  
        throw e;
    } finally {  
        chSftp.quit();  
        channel.disconnect();  
        session.disconnect();  
    }  
 }
```

Without going through the JSch code (which is available on GitHub BTW), I believe that adding a user information POJO to the session before connecting has a different effect than adding the password to the session itself

## Logging - an after thought

The poster above my figured out the issue with the code I posted and solved the original posters question.  I went over the Session code in the JSch library and saw that enabling logging for JSch would have helped you immensely here.  Here is a sample that enables logging.

*MyLogger class*

> Code from Jsch Example

```
  public static class MyLogger implements com.jcraft.jsch.Logger {
    static java.util.Hashtable name=new java.util.Hashtable();
    static{
      name.put(new Integer(DEBUG), "DEBUG: ");
      name.put(new Integer(INFO), "INFO: ");
      name.put(new Integer(WARN), "WARN: ");
      name.put(new Integer(ERROR), "ERROR: ");
      name.put(new Integer(FATAL), "FATAL: ");
    }
    public boolean isEnabled(int level){
      return true;
    }
    public void log(int level, String message){
      System.err.print(name.get(new Integer(level)));
      System.err.println(message);
    }
  }
```

And to enable it simple modify your code

```
Session session = null;  
Channel channel = null;  
JSch.setLogger(new MyLogger());

JSch jsch = new JSch();  
session = jsch.getSession(ftpUserName, ftpHost, ftpPort);  
if (session == null) {  
    throw new Exception("session is null");  
}  
session.setPassword(ftpPassword);  
session.setTimeout(100000);  
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");  
session.connect();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, according to your proposal  the problem still exists.And in my "SessionUserInfo.java" it do more than a method.It is "@Override
  public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String arg0, String arg1,
    String arg2, String[] arg3, boolean[] arg4) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
  }".I don't know if this method is affected.

Comment: I'm glad another poster was able to remove the gssapi-with-mi and have it work.  Going through the code online I'm still not sure why my example isn't working for you.  But, either way, glad its figured out.  ALSO, I updated my original post at the end to include a little piece on logging.  Going through the jsch session code I see it would have been very beneficial if this was enabled when you were running the program for troubleshooting purposes